# navigator handlers value in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, navigator

I want to get navigator handlers value in my highstock tooltip formatter.

I can get the min and max of my xAxis in tooltip(my navigator min date and max date).

Please help me...

Thanks

Comment: Any jsFiddle with that issue? If you can get in tooltip min and max for xAxis, where is the problem? getExtremes() returns actual min and max.

Comment: I mean I can get the min and max of my chart when the rangeSelector is on the all but when I change my xAxis by navigator handler I can not find the left and right handlers value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get extremes in formatter this way:

```
 this.points[0].series.xAxis.getExtremes();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/E83Ef/